# Limit authorization into SQL Server for stored procedure - only calls

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, authorization

In order to keep my database's data integrity, I am trying to unauthorize all the queries that aren't calls to a stored procedure. But I don't want queries that I run directly from SQL Server to be blocked because then I will be unable to make any changes to the database (If the database cannot differentiate between "inside" queries and "outside" queries, maybe queries will be allowed under a particular authorization). How can I do such a thing?

Comment: You have multiple users setup, some users are admin and have full access, some users are not and can only call SPs.

Comment: Make use of separate database users (via SQL Logins) and SQL Server's [GRANT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-transact-sql) permissions. i.e.: apply no permissions to tables such that only sys admins and db owners can access them, then only apply `grant execute` permissions to the stored procedures that your lesser-privileged users should be allowed to invoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom application role in your database that can only execute those stored procedures - but doesn't have any permissions to read or update data directly.

The simplest approach I usually take is this:

- Create a custom database role `db_executor` which works similar to `db_datareader`
- Grant this role the permission to execute all current and future stored procedures
- Create users that only get this role - these users can connect to your database and they can only execute stored procedures - nothing else

**Step 1 - create new role**

```
CREATE ROLE [db_executor]
```

**Step 2 - grant permissions**

```
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor;
```

This grants the permission to execute *any* stored procedures in this database - and the great thing is: this doesn't apply to just the stored procedures that exist at the time you run this - this will also include any stored procedures you might create in the future

**Step 3 - add user(s) to this role**

You can do this in the GUI of course - or using this T-SQL:

```
ALTER ROLE [db_executor] ADD MEMBER [your-user-name-here]
```